# Is it possible to have a custom facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Sometimes, clients want to have a custom "facebook button". I mean with a different image and design.

I used to work with sharer.php :

```
<a id="fb-share" style='text-decoration:none;' type="icon_link" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=foo&amp;p[summary]=bar&amp;p[url]=https://www.foobar.com/&amp;p[images][0]=https://www.foobar.com/thumb.gif','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">
<img src="img/share.gif" width="62" height="18" alt="Share"/>
S</a>
```

But it seems it doesn't work very well since facebook has deprecated the Share button. Instead, we have to use the "like button".

So is it possible to have a custom like button with a custom image ?

I've seen on the facebook api page a [generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to create the button but i would like to know if it is possible to have a custom button with a different image ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's possible with a lot of work.

Basically, you have to post [likes action via the Open Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/likes/). Then, you can add a custom design to your like button.

But then, you''ll need to keep track yourself of the likes so a returning user will be able to unlike content he liked previously.

Plus, you'll need to ask user to [log into your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/) and ask them the `publish_action` permission.

All in all, if you're doing this for an application, it may worth it. For a website where you basically want user to like articles, then this is really to much.

Also, consider that you increase your drop-off rate each time you ask user a permission via a Facebook login.

*If you want to see an example, I've [recently made an app using the open graph like button](https://www.facebook.com/iogo/app_481212558596438), just hover on some photos in the mosaique to see it*

Comment: Thank you. You answer is clear. Your example is smart. But, in my case, it is for a website so, as you suggest, i won't use it. Is there an alternative to the "like button" or is it the only thing i could use to share a web page on Facebook ?

Comment: This is the most relevant (and easy) usage. It's well known from user. But, for sharing a web page, you could also use the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: I'm actually trying "Feed dialog". It seems to be the same thing as "sharing" and i think i could use it. Do you know the purpose of the property app_id ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's used somehow to authenticate/initialize your app.

Comment: So, i've tried and it's working on a website but i think it should not be used on a website, only on a facebook app i guess...

Comment: However you are wrong about users unliking a page by liking it twice, trying to re-publish a built-in Like action on an Open Graph object that has already been “liked” by the user in the past will result in the following error

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3501) User is already associated to the object with the Like action type. Original Action ID: 396497300390731",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3501
  }
}

Comment: @Neo You must have misread, I never implied reposting the same action would delete the like.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I did misread... I read " so a returning user will not be able to unlike " thinking that you meant clicking on like again will unlike it :D