# change the text of Facebook Like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to change the "like" text of the Facebook like button. is it possible ?

this is a code i am using for like button.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=187194041405509" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a custom facebook like button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801757/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as you can only access content of iframe if domain you are accessing iframe and domain of iframe are same, and as facebook is different from your site it is not possible.