# Is it possible to change the css style of facebook like button in html

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I want to change the css style (like width height and image) of facebook like button whick is attached in html page with help of following facebook script :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

So, is it possible or not and if possible then what is code for that

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible.

You can only use the button provided by Facebook

See : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

And this question on stackoverflow :
[Is it possible to have a custom facebook like button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801757/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-facebook-like-button)

Comment: It seems to be possible if you handle yourself all the like process through Facebook API; but it sounds like a lot of trouble for a simple blog. 
See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801757/is-it-possible-to-have-a-custom-facebook-like-button